# "expected ' ; ' after return statement, could someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I tried my level best but couldn't figure out what is going wrong with my code.
I'm getting an **error** code `"error: expected ' ; ' after return statement."`

**Note:** This is my first program besides "hello world", any help will be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int celsius, fahrenheit;

//Get degrees in celsius
cout << "Please input degrees Celsius: \n";
cin >> celsius;

//convert celsius to fahrenheit
fahrenheit = celsius * 1.8 + 32;

//display degrees farhenheit/ thank you message
cout << "\n" << "Degrees Fahrenheit: \n" << fahrenheit << "\n";
cout << "\n" << "Thank you for using my Celsius to Fahrenheit converter. \n" << "\n";

    {
        int yes = 1, no = 0;
        cout << "do you wish to convert again? \n";
        cin >> yes;

        if (yes == 1) {
            return cout << "please enter degrees Celsius" ;
            cin >> celsius;

            //convert celsius to fahrenheit
            fahrenheit = celsius * 1.8 + 32;
            cout << "\n" << "Degrees Fahrenheit: \n" << fahrenheit << "\n";
        } else {
            return cout "fine";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have unnecessary braces `{ }` too.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you have made 3 mistakes in your code:

1.In the if block you have written `return cout << "please enter degrees Celsius" ;`(line 31). But cout doesn't return anything (see the P.S. below for details.). Change it to `cout << "please enter degrees Celcius";`

2. In the else block you have written `return cout "fine";` (line 41). Change it to `cout << "fine";`
3. You have the unused variable **"no"** in your code. It is only there but does not take part in the code. Remove that variable.

Your final code should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

   int main()
{

int celsius, fahrenheit;

//Get degrees in celsius
cout << "Please input degrees Celsius: \n";

cin >> celsius;

//convert celsius to fahrenheit
fahrenheit = celsius * 1.8 + 32;

//display degrees farhenheit/ thank you message
cout << "\n" << "Degrees Fahrenheit: \n" << fahrenheit << "\n";
cout << "\n" << "Thank you for using my Celsius to Fahrenheit converter. \n" << "\n";


   int yes = 1;

   cout << "do you wish to convert again? \n";
   cin >> yes;

        if (yes == 1)
            {
                cout << "please enter degrees Celsius" ;
                cin >> celsius;

                //convert celsius to fahrenheit
                fahrenheit = celsius * 1.8 + 32;

                cout << "\n" << "Degrees Fahrenheit: \n" << fahrenheit << "\n";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "fine";
            }
return 0;


}
```

P.S. The operator "<<" does return a `std::ostream` object which is `cout`. This object can be converted to bool but not to an int. But as you are completely new to c++, you don't need to worry about that just yet. Just use the code I showed you.

Comment: `cout` doesn't return anything is, I suppose, true enough because `cout` is a thing, not an operator. The operator is `<<`, and it *does* return something; the overload in use here (`std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const char*)`) returns a stream; specifically, the same stream as is used as the left-hand operand. So `cout << "foo"` returns `cout`. `std::ostream` objects can be converted to `bool` values (the conversion is true if the stream is ok to write to) but they can't be converted to `int`. So the statement is incorrect (and the return undesired) but not for the reason you give.

Comment: What I meant to say in my answer is that cout does not return the value of the temperature. It just shows the value on his screen. I just did not want to confuse him by telling him about ostream objects and operator overloading. So I just told him to remove "return" from those statements and use "<<" after cout.

Comment: The desire to not confuse is noble but feeding the popular misconception that something starting `cout <<` is a "cout statement" *creates* confusion. OP may not understand what `return` does, but your answer doesn't promote that understanding either.

Comment: Okay man, I just added a P.S. stating that "<<" returns a std::ostream object. Now my answer should not spread any misconception.

Answer (score 1):

Remove two junk `return` before `cout` and add `<<` between `cout` and `"fine"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
return cout << "please enter degrees Celsius" ; //line 31
return cout "fine"; //line 41
```

remove return from both the statements.

cout is the object of `ostream` class.You can read more about `cout` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/)